# If formulas to copy

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy

Can the if formula be used to copy a cell based on two other cells. I.E
I and trying to have what’s in j copy to another cell if h=5/23/2022 and I= a time after 12:15 then p=j?

Comment: `ifs` takes multiple criteria, use that or nest multiple `if`

Comment: Look at AND(): `=IF(AND(H1=DATE(2022,5,23),I1>=TIME(12,15,0)),J1,"")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.